# Erev rav - the people of the children of Israel?

Tags: passover, commentaries

I would like to ask a question before the erev of Pesach begins.

I found this article online [of the chabad website](https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/2054268/jewish/A-Man-of-Insight.htm) and in it the claim is being made that Yosef and Ya'akov converted different people in Egypt and that these people got circumcised.

> These are **the Mixed Multitude [the "Erev Rav"]** of whom the Egyptians said, "**the people of the Children of Israel** are more numerous and stronger than us" (Ex. 1:9). But a later verse states, "and they [the Egyptians] became dissatisfied with themselves because of the Children of Israel" (Ex. 1:12). [In one verse they are referred to as "the people of the Children of Israel," whereas in the other they are referred to as simply "the Children of Israel." Why the discrepancy?]
>
> The secret of this is that those whom Joseph circumcised, and who lived in the Jewish cities, observed the customs of the Israelites. Jacob had also converted Egyptians, as our Sages state (Bereishit Rabba section 4). All of them also observed Israelite customs. Now Pharaoh noticed [the observances of] those who were called "the people of the Children of Israel," i.e. those who were not the Children of Israel themselves, but the people of the Children of Israel. Therefore another verse states, "He [Pharaoh] said to his nation…" (Ex. 1:9) i.e. other Egyptians, who were not the people of the Children of Israel. But the verse "and they became dissatisfied with themselves because of the Children of Israel" refers to the Israelites themselves.

Was there really a group in Egypt which converted to Judiasm?